# how to use return method in backgroundworker

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

i use background worker to call method but in return give me an Exception here is the code

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     BGW.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

void BGW_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Result = new Drug_Class().Search(Filter);
    }

class Drug_Class
{

    public List<WorkSpaceVariable.Drug_List> Search(Expression<Func<db.Drug_Catalog, bool>> Filter)
    {
        using (db.PVDBDataContext PVDB=new PVDBDataContext ())
        {

            try
            {

                  var DQuary = from D in PVDB.Drug_Catalogs.Where(Filter)
                    select new WorkSpaceVariable.Drug_List
                    {
                        Drugs_ID = D.Drugs_ID
                    }


                   return DQuary.ToList() ;//Exception The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

            }

            catch (Exception E)
            {

                return null;
            }

        }


}
```

i don't understand why i got this Exception may any one tell me whats wrong with my code ?

Comment: You should post the exception you're getting

Comment: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Exception` that you got really explains your problem... all you need to do is to read it:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

You should hopefully know that a `BackgroundWorker` works on a background thread, so you should be able to work out that the two threads mentioned would be this background thread and the main UI thread.

What it means is that you cannot manipulate UI objects that were declared on (and therefore owned by) the main UI thread on any other thread.

The solution is to not manipulate UI objects from the UI thread in your background thread. Instead, just manipulate the data in the background thread and when the `BackgroundWorker` has finished, then update the UI element by updating the data bound collection.

Comment: I know what you said i just select from database and return list no UI in my code and thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Then the second thread is *not* the UI thread... it makes no difference though. The problem is still caused because you're trying to manipulate an object that was created on one thread in another... just look through your code and you should find it. The fix is the same... don't mix objects from different threads.

Comment: No I don't mean that... there wouldn't be much point in a `BackgroundWorker` if that were the case.